# ACCESS SQL IN function with wildcard

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I make Access treat `*1*` as a string instead of using wildcard in the SQL
`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID IN ("*1*","*2*");`?

Comment: It is working fine in my code. `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID IN ('*1*','*2*');` What are you trying to fetch?

Comment: @MaheshWaghmare are you using MS Access? The OP is talking about Access not SQL Server. Access uses the `*` as the wildcard equivalent to SQL's `%`. Note that `[*]` works like the SQL underscore `_` as a single character match.

Comment: @daShier Sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is a limitation of Access. You can use `[*]` to search for any single character, so:

```sql
    TABLE1 WHERE ID IN ("[*]1[*]","[*]2[*]")
```

Would match any single leading and trailing character with `1` or `2` in the middle. Not what you want, but closer.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression:

```
WHERE ID IN ("*1*", "*2*")
```

MS Access *does* treat the values as strings and not wildcards.  The wildcards are only used for `LIKE`.

If you want them to be treated as wildcards, you need to use `LIKE`.  That would require `OR`:

```
WHERE ID LIKE "*1*" OR ID LIKE "*2*"
```

Or more simply as:

```
WHERE ID LIKE "*[1-2]*"
```